# How to get the value of a touchLocation from a subclassed UIScrollView to the mainViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Since the touch functions won't work until they are subclasses for the `UIScrollView`, I have subclassed them and get the touch coordinates in the subclass. But all my operations are being done in `MainViewController`. How can I send this value there? Might seem an easy question, but it is taking a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your answer is, but I just learned this technology a few days ago also.  It was that, in the  touchesBegan method of the view, I called

```
[self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
```

and then wrote the touches began event in the view controller to which this passed the event.

Seems like no solution could be simpler.

John Doner

Comment: Simpler solution is to call `[super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];`